# How to get a continuous scale bar in pheatmap

Tags: r, pheatmap

I am working on microarray data and to represent the data, we chose to use heatmaps. I used `pheatmap` for the same.

Using the code

```
my_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("green", "black", "red"))(n = 9999)

pheatmap(dts, color = my_palette, cluster_rows=T, cluster_cols=F,
         show_rownames=F, main="All Conditions", border_color=NA, 
         labels_col=c("SKF","ABeta","CSP","TTK21"))
```

I obtained [image: the heatmap]

As you can see in the top right corner of the image is the scale bar, which shows a white gap around the value of -2.5

Kindly update me regarding any errors in the code, because I set up the palette according to available code.

Edit: Sample data (stored as matrix, named list)

```
dts <- read.table(text="
Gene     SKF     ABeta     CSP     TTK21
A     0.05466     -0.0154254     0.011404     0.96582
B     1.05325     0.015212     0.22360     10.00140254
C     2.002102     20.200052     1.214325     1.25355
D     0.05466     -0.0154254     0.011404     0.96582
E     1.05325     0.015212     0.22360     10.00140254
F     2.002102     20.200052     1.214325     1.25355
G     0.05466     -0.0154254     0.011404     0.96582
H     1.05325     0.015212     0.22360     10.00140254
I     2.002102     20.200052     1.214325     1.25355
", header=T)
```

P.S. In the sample, I have repeated the data of the first three genes thrice, but the problem can be understood. The pattern of the heatmap is not going to be reproducible as shown above, but the white gap persists.

Thank you.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce you problem. Please provide a [minimal workable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with some data!

Comment: Thank you for your request, I have edited the question and have added a sample data. I tried the same on my console, and the white gap persists. It also stays when the plot is saved either as an image or pdf.

Comment: @vinayrao I am unable to replicate the problem. Please, try using the data set `dts <- matrix((runif(1000*4)*18-7), ncol=4)` with the code reported in your post. Let me know.